# Is there a way to change the default docstring text generated by Spyder when creating a new function?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, docstring

I am trying to change the default docstring text that Spyder generates when creating a new function. I like how I can automatically create a docstring template, but I wanted to change the text. If you don't know what I mean, here is the docstring Spyder generates:

```
def example_function(n):
    """


    Parameters
    ----------
    n : TYPE
        DESCRIPTION.

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
```

I would be grateful if anyone has a way to change this text. Thanks.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) By `docstring text` you mean the template text introduced by Spyder?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Yes I do, I don't mean the default module docstring that appears at the top of the file

Comment: Ok, good to know. Answer coming.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to change the template text introduced by Spyder to create docstrings.

However, you can select between two different types of docstring formats (Numpy and Google) by going to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Editor > Advanced settings > Docstring type`.